# Run VB Script from Windows Service

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have written a small Windows Service in C# which executes .BAT and .VBS scripts. The following code triggers the .vbs script:

```
string path = "C:\\Path\\To\\MyScript.vbs";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C C:\\Windows\\System32\\cscript.exe //Nologo \"" + path + "\"";
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
p.ErrorDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

try
{
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
}
catch { // }
```

The code compiles and runs without any exceptions. However, there miust be something wrong since the VBS script does not execute until the end. Inside the script, I open a telnet session and enter some commands. When I run the same code and the same script in a WinForms Application, everything works perfectly fine.

I assume the problem is caused by my service, which runs as LOCAL SYSTEM.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is my VBScript:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 1000 

WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 127.0.0.1 3000"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 2000

WshShell.SendKeys "reboot application"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

For some reason, the telnet command is never executed, but the Process still ends with exitcode '0'...

Comment: Did you debug the service and see what happens ?

Comment: I did, but I get neither an exception nor any error message...

Comment: You might not get exception but Process.Start() might throw error code. Check process.ExitCode and you should get the integer describing the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The process exits with '0', so it looks like everything is okay. I will add the VB script above to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - SendKeys does not work when no user is logged in. The code itself works perfectly fine.